# Can we have the user activity on the top-bar?

Tags: feature-request, activity-tab

From the 3 most important things I use 2 is already on the top-bar (well done):

- The Inbox
- The Reputation (Achievements)

The 3rd thing I frequently need is the *Activity tab*.

I often get new ideas/solutions, or realize that I made a mistake, or want to make some edits, see what others posted, etc. You get the idea. It's a way to *navigate back* to a place where I left a comment or answer.

Could we add this to the top-bar? I know I can bookmark it, but if others use it as often as I do, then it would be certainly beneficial for them as well. There's certainly plenty of place there for an extra image. What I'm trying to figure out: is there a *need* as well?

Comment: The two items in your top bar are there to draw your attention when changes occur. Your own activities are no such changes; you just created those yourself by your own actions. You can easily reach that tab with two clicks; one on your icon to get to your profile, another to get to the activity tab.

Comment: I'm aware of that.

Comment: You can also favorite [your activity tab](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/650405/karoly-horvath?tab=activity&sort=all), or pin it in a permanent tab if your browser can do that.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that (note: you have to reload the page...). Looks like you guys either don't use this feature (much) or love to click...

Comment: Every browser already supports this.  Try pressing Ctrl+H

Comment: Would you guys please stop explaining a 48k user what a browser can do? Yes, and I can also add a user script that puts there a button....

Comment: We're not, you are only 47.9k, and  48k is the threshold for assuming knowledge of browsers :P

Comment: give me a couple of sec... :P

Comment: +1, I navigate this site largely from my Activity tab to check on posts I've edited, answered or commented on. I think more people should do so, and letting that take one click less is a step towards a greater SO.

Comment: +1; I too would like to have that. I often want to check my latest comments and posts, and having a shortcut to that within the top bar would be really useful.

Comment: This link _used_ to exist in the same pop-down that showed rep changes and votes; I also found it very useful. I was never sure why all that stuff was removed from easy accessibility.

Comment: `I often get new ideas/solutions, or realize that I made a mistake, or want to make some edits, see what others posted, etc. You get the idea. It's a way to navigate back to a place where I left a comment or answer.` isn't the site itself a great place to do all this?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: this is all *related* to the page I left a comment or answer on. E.g.: I posted an answer, but 5 minutes later when I'm concentrating on something completely different suddenly I realize that I wrote something that was incorrect. Or I realize there's a better way to solve the problem. So I want to go back and fix it...

Answer (score 7):

**Yes**, I would love to see such a feature, I very often use the *Activity tab*.

It *was* available on the top-bar before it was re-designed, and now I'm badly miss it.

We could also add some "real-time" functionality to it, for example showing which page listed in the activity tab had new activity on it. So the activity pull-down will show *your* activites, and next to each you'll see whether *others* made new activity at the same *location* (question or answer).

Example:

- There is a new comment on the Q/A where you left a comment.
- The OP updated the question for which you left a comment/answer.

You could show this with icons and counters (e.g.: 3 "new comment icon").

I think this would be in line with the notion @MartijnPieters described in the comments - that is, to draw your attention when changes occur.

Comment: "also add some real-time functionality to it, for example showing which page listed in the activity tab had new activity on it (new comment, new answer, updated question, etc" So, I make a comment, and I get a notification letting me know I have just made a comment? I post an answer, and I get a notification I answered a question, some 2 seconds ago? I don't understand.

Comment: Why on earth would you (like to) get notifications on your *own* activities? You won't.

Comment: I really don't want to seem to be being argumentative, I'm really not. But you're not being very clear. In your proposal you stated "*It's a way to navigate back to a place where **I** left a comment or answer*", but now you state "*Why on earth would you (like to) get notifications on your own activities*". You have to be clear when you're proposing something :)  For *what* **exactly** do you want to get notifications or info in the top bar?

Comment: However crazy may that sound to you, my main goal was that one-click approach (no new page, no page reload, no scrolling, direct access). But you're right my description was very sloopy. See the update.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful with adding controls to UI. It's one additional control for you, but one of many for new user. New user may be totally lost in bloated UI. It will be perceived as a mess.

I think that thing behind success of sites such as youtube or google was their simplicity in both design (boring white sites with few graphics elements) and UI. This applied to stackoverflow also (recently it's like changing unfortunately).

Comment: I completely agree. However, what you've described is nothing more than a general guideline. You should tailor it so that it addresses the actual question. Hm... I'm not even sure it's doable... after all, it's just a guideline.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath it's general but you can apply it for your particular question. For me it's no for additional control. UI redesign - maybe.